# How to merge multiple json file with same naming convention together

Tags: python, json

I have multiple json files with the below naming convention: `"name_s1.json", "name_s2.json", "name_s3.json"`. I have 30 such files with 10 different names. Now I'd like to join the files with the same name together. For example, "apple_s2.json" and "apple_s3.json" will be merged into "apple_s1.json". Similarly, "banana_s2.json" and "banana_s3.json" will be merged into "banana_s1.json".

The final file will be saved as `"apple.json"` and `"banana.json"`. How do I best accomplish the task?

To obtain the name, the code i used is:

```
name = os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('_', 1)[0]
```

However, I am relatively new to json file merging in Python. Not sure how to proceed from here. Thanks!

Comment: There's no generic way to merge JSON, since it depends on the structure of it. Are they dictionaries or lists, do you need to merge recursively, etc.?

Comment: You need to use `json.load()` to load the JSON into Python dictionaries or lists, then use application-specific code to combine them.